# Regular expression to match phone number?

Tags: regex, phone-number

I want to match a phone number that can have letters and an optional hyphen:

- This is valid: `333-WELL`
- This is also valid: `4URGENT`

In other words, there can be at most one hyphen but if there is no hyphen, there can be at most seven 0-9 or A-Z characters.

I dont know how to do and "if statement" in a regex. Is that even possible?

Comment: An answer has been accepted, but I'd like to know: Can that hyphen be anywhere in the number, or must it always be (if at all) between the 3rd and 4th digit?

Comment: Is there a reason that you *need* to use a regex?

Comment: @Carl Smotricz: it can be anywhere. good question.

Comment: @voyager: I'm writing the XSD restriction pattern facet. So yes, I need to use regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seek the alternation operator, indicated with pipe character: `|`

However, you may need either 7 alternatives (1 for each hyphen location + 1 for no hyphen), or you may require the hyphen between 3rd and 4th character and use 2 alternatives.

One use of alternation operator defines two alternatives, as in:

```
({3,3}[0-9A-Za-z]-{4,4}[0-9A-Za-z]|{7,7}[0-9A-Za-z])
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this should do it:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}-?[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$/
```

It matches 3 letters or numbers followed by an optional hyphen followed by 4 letters or numbers.  This one works in ruby.  Depending on the regex engine you're using you may need to alter it slightly.

Comment: i have one question..so i tested the above regex, and it works fine. however, when i add more digits to the end, the regex validator still says it's valid. why is that? shouldnt the expression become invalid as soon as i add 1 more character? i test at http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/ using 121333333

Comment: @ShaChris23 because 121333333 also matches it at the beginning.  For true full length matching, it'd be `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}-?[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$/` (use the `^` and `$` symbols to denote beginning of string and end of string (respectively))

Comment: thank you, Dave! wow..I feel like I learned quite a bit from this one example. (^_^)

Comment: This is a really good answer.  In some ways, it is better than my (accepted) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this counts, but I'd break it into two regexes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = '333-URGE';

print "Format OK\n" if $text =~ m/^[\dA-Z]{1,6}-?[\dA-Z]{1,6}$/;
print "Length OK\n" if $text =~ m/^(?:[\dA-Z]{7}|[\dA-Z-]{8})$/;
```

This should avoid accepting multiple dashes, dashes in the wrong place, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you want to allow the hyphen to be anywhere, [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will be of use to you. Something like this:

```
^([A-Z0-9]{7}|(?=^[^-]+-[^-]+$)[A-Z0-9-]{8})$
```

There are two main parts to this pattern: `[A-Z0-9]{7}` to match a hyphen-free string and `(?=^[^-]+-[^-]+$)[A-Z0-9-]{8}` to match a hyphenated string.

The `(?=^[^-]+-[^-]+$)` will match for any string with a SINGLE hyphen in it (and the hyphen isn't the first or last character), then the `[A-Z0-9-]{8}` part will count the characters and make sure they are all valid.

Comment: Note: I revised my answer after testing the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Heath Hunnicutt for his alternation operator answer as well as showing me an example.

Based on his advice, here's my answer:

```
[A-Z0-9]{7}|[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9-]{7}
```

Note: I tested my regex [here](http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/). (Just including this for reference)

Comment: This will consider `0------` to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I use a or with two patterns 7 alpha numeric characters or 3 alpha numeric character a hyphen and 4 alpha numeric characters

```
def check_string(string):
    if re.match(r'^[A-Z0-9]{7}$|^[A-Z0-9]{3}-[A-Z0-9]{4}$', string):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```