# javascript regular expression phone number validation

Tags: javascript

I would like to test if the right phone number was enterred in the text field.
The phone number should be ddd-ddddddd which means 3digits then must have "-" and then 7 digits.
How do I set the regular expression for that ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736686/regular-expression-to-match-phone-number/1736690#1736690

Comment: I hate sites that require exact formats like that.  It's so easy to scan through the digits alone and then add the dashes as necessary. /rant

Comment: The format asked for is not the same.

Comment: I hate sites that require exact formats that only apply to one country. (Unless they make it really clear on the front page that they only deal with residents of that country, and even then - why?) /rant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as you say it `/^\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d\d$/`

Comment: There's an extra `\d` before your hyphen. I'd suggest you use `{n}` instead, as it's less error-prone.

Comment: corrected, thanks, I used this method because it looks very close to how the questioner represented the format himself.

Comment: @nobody, your trick didn't work. var phoneNumberPatteern = /^\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d\d$/;
 if (phoneNumberPattern.test(phone) == false)

Comment: @nobody, I understand what you mean, and it might be a good idea (and maybe your answer will be the accepted one if the questioner understands it best). However, limits in the question should not necessarily lead to limited answers: repeating `\d` doesn't scale, and if the questioner doesn't know that, doing the same in your answer won't teach him anything.

Comment: @AlonB I just tested this code in firefox: `var phoneNumberPattern = /^\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d\d$/; alert( phoneNumberPattern.test('555-7777777') );` result: true

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I didn't disagree with you, of course the \d{n} method is the better way to go I was just clarifying what was on my mind when I used repeated \d s.

Comment: @nobody - did you test it with letters ? someone can input latters and it didnt fail for me

Comment: @AlonB you mean letters instead of numbers? then you should change the pattern to this: /^\w\w\w-\w\w\w\w\w\w\w$/ one problem though it will accept underlines too.

Answer (score 3):

```
/^\d{3}-\d{7}$/.test( phone_number );
```

Comment: didn't work, can i set it var patt = /^\d{3}-\d{7}$/; and then do patt.test(phonenumber)?

Answer (score 2):

```
var phoneNumber = '123-1234567';
if(phoneNumber.match(/^\d{3}-\d{7}$/))
{
   alert('blah');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's my take:

```
/^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{7}$/
```