# I need a regex for a telephone number which does not accept 0 as the first digit of the 3 digit US area code

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently working with the following regex to match a phone number

```
'\\([1-9]{3}\\)\\s{1}[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'
```

But the above pattern is not allowing 0 in the first 3 digits and when I modify it to

```
'\\([0-9]{3}\\)\\s{1}[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'
```

it is accepting 0 as the first digit. I would like to generate a regex which would not accept 0 for the first digit but does accept for the remaining digits.

I have modified the regex which I think will suit my needs but I am not entirely sure ( never ever did a regex pattern) and dont know how to test it on regex101

```
'\\([1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}\\)\\s{1}[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'
```

if someone can help me out as in if you could point out if I am going in the right direction that would be amazing

I am looking for inverse of whats in this question, the answers in this make sure the number begins with a 0 but I am looking for inverse of the following implementation

[Javascript Regex - What to use to validate a phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639973/javascript-regex-what-to-use-to-validate-a-phone-number)

Thank you,
Vijay

Comment: number telephone example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Regex - What to use to validate a phone number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639973/javascript-regex-what-to-use-to-validate-a-phone-number)

Comment: @Edulynch
phone number examples :--
208-123-4567
280-123-4567

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\([1-9]\d\d\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}/;
```

Or:

```
new RegExp('\\([1-9]\\d\\d\\)\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}');
```

**Explanation:**

```
\(    : open paren
[1-9] : a digit (not 0)
\d\d  : 2 digits (including 0)
\)    : close paren
\s    : one space
\d{3} : 3 digits (including 0)
-     : hyphen
\d{4} : 4 digits (including 0)
```

Comment: That is a great explanation but I am not sure if I am testing it correctly on www.regex101.com 
the phone number i am entering to test as per your explanation is 
(200) 123-4567 and the test fails, am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @Vijay One note: If you are using this regex to test if a string is a valid number (`regex.test(string)`) then you may want to add anchors at the beginig (`^`) and the end (`$`) like this: `/^\([1-9]\d\d\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/`.

Answer (score 1):

This Should Work.

Regexp:

```
[1-9]\d{2}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}
```

Input:

```
208-123-4567
099-123-4567
280-123-4567
```

Output:

```
208-123-4567
280-123-4567
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
const regex = /[1-9]\d{2}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}/gm;
const str = `208-123-4567
099-123-4567
280-123-4567`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/3DKEas/1