# Parse International Phone numbers from web pages

Tags: c#, regex, html-agility-pack, phone-number

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to parse the webpages. once the document is loaded, I want to extract the possible phone numbers from HTML. Currently, I am using some regex for this purpose. I have following piece of code that checks for the match of phone numbers in webpage

```
    private static string phoneReg =
                @"[\+]{0,1}(\d{10,13}|[\(][\+]{0,1}\d{2,}[\13)]*\d{5,13}|\d{2,6}[\-]{1}\d{2,13}[\-]*\d{3,13})";
            private static Regex phoneRegex = new Regex(phoneReg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var phoneMatches = phoneRegex.Matches(doci.DocumentNode.InnerText);
```

where `doci` is `HtmlDocument` abstraction from html agility pack. The problem is that it fails to match some phone numbers like `08450 211 211` and `+44 (0) 1246 733 000`.

Is there a generic regex expression that is most suitable when crawling websites and it allows the matching of most forms of international phone numbers?

Comment: I have tried many regex patterns from http://www.regexlib.com but they do not serve the purpose

Comment: I'm sorry, but that sound malicious to me out of context. (Crawling on a lot of web sites and extracting phone numbers). Would you mind shedding some light on why you're doing this?

Comment: This is about collecting some information about the distributor that are present on our website. we just read there website from db and try to extract their contact info.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared this up. First of all I would not use HAP, it's very outdated. Consider CsQuery it's a lot easier to work with. Second, what did not work for you in other SO questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736686/regular-expression-to-match-phone-number?

Comment: I have seen that pattern but it does not work with this scenario

Comment: I can even set for more than on regex expressions. will just try to match them one by one

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - could you expand on HAP being "very outdated"?

Comment: @SimonMourier Hey! First of all let me thank you for all your great work on HAP. It saved me hundreds of hours of work. I really appreciate it. If you look at CsQuery it uses query selectors which are a _lot_ more common than XPATH for HTML today. Second, CsQuery is a lot _faster_ than HAP because it indexes selectors, I've seen a 100%+ performance gain in my projects (You can grab the benchmarks in CsQuery's github). The HAP API seems to me less similar to native .NET interfaces (CsQuery is very "LINQ'y). I've also had plenty of cases where CsQuery managed to parse the page and HAP did not.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - this is very personal. I prefer XPATH to LINQ for example (no need to handle null cases for example). Concerning the plenty of cases where HAP didn't parse pages when it really should, I'm dubious (ps: if you want, you can contact me, my email can be found 'encoded' in HAP home page)

Comment: would anyone plz attend to the issue in question

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Although I agree with you, I don't think HTMLAgilityPack is outdated at all. I mean, *outdated* is not the best word. By the way, I knew about this because of the issue you posted in CsQuery's github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match those phone numbers (`08450 211 211` and `+44 (0) 1246 733 000`) because your regex simply doesn't match them.

The first thing you have to do when writing a regular expression is **to identify the pattern you want to match**.

So, my suggestion is to write down a **list of the different phone number formats**, **update your question**, and then we will be able to help you. Otherwise I will always create a new phone number that your regex might not match, or it will just match more than whan you want.

Here is a regex that will match the above phone numbers:

```
(?:\+\d+\s+\(\d+\)\s+)?\d{4,5}\s+\d{3}\s+\d{3}
```

**Edit:**

According to your comment, I would just use this regex, and then remove the ones that are not phone numbers:

```
(?:\+\d+\s+\(\d+\)\s+)?[\d -]+
```

Comment: Actually, I want to extract phone numbers from websites of different distributors, so comming up with an exact data set is very difficult. What, I want is a regex pattern that matches most of international phone number patterns. False positives are tolerable to some extent. Unless they start declaring text or html as phone number.

Comment: when parsing documents for presence of phone numbers, adding `^` will force matching only at the start of the document. similarly adding `$` at the end will force matching only at the end of the document. Is it true or I am misreading how the regex works

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid See my edit. I think you could use that regular expression, and then just remove manually the incorrect ones, since there will be incorrect numbers (like this date: `2010-10-10`, etc.). Once you have a long list, perhaps you can group the numbers according to their format, and write a more specific regex.

Comment: what's the meaning of `?:` in regex?

Comment: That means `Do not capture this group`. It is matched, but not placed in the groups list. It probably can be omitted in this case. You can adjust the parenthesis depending on what you want to capture in each group.

Comment: Ok, thanks. any word about removing false positives afterwards?